# Can't assign PIP to existed VM threw error 'PublicIP per Virtual Machine usage not allowed for this deployment.'

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I used following script to assign a PIP to my VM, but it always throw error 'Update-AzureVM : BadRequest : PublicIP per Virtual Machine usage not allowed for this deployment.'

script: *Get-AzureVM -ServiceName gbv2 -Name gbv2 | Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName mypip | Update-AzureVM*

And I found a interesting post http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/assign-public-ip-addresses-azure-vms/#comment-217651 about this problem it said if VM use 'old-style' VNet will cause this problem, but didn't mention the solution. Could you guys give me some clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting here.

I suggest you to follow this  article which briefs about setting PIP to VMs. I tried assigning  a PIP to my VM and it worked successfully. Please make sure to follow all the steps from beginning. It helps a lot.

http://www.jonprocter.com/assign-a-public-ip-pip-to-an-azure-virtual-machine-vm/

Girish Prajwal

Comment: Thanks Girish, do you know how to assign a PIP to a existed VM?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am afraid to say that we cannot add PIP to existing VM. I will check with VM experts and keep you informed at the earliest.

Comment: It seems to only be possible to assign a reserved IP to a VM that has a network set up. If you have an existing VM, you can capture an image. Delete the old VM. Create a new VM from the image, setting the network. Then using `azure vm public-ip set` you can assign a reserved IP.

Comment: "azure vm public-ip set" only sets the instance ip?